# Media queries ignored, following MDN guidelines

Tags: css

I'm getting really frustrated by this...

MDN example media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

My media query:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .nav-content {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
}
```

It's not working...

Things I have checked for:

- Query is after original .nav-content declaration
- The class is the right name
- Spelling is correct

The original CSS

```
.nav-content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a link to a codepen: http://codepen.io/sbhenrichs/pen/ZOjyrm
But when I shrink the browser down to less than 1000px, nothing is happening!

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Can't really help you if we can't reproduce the problem. Post the full code, or a working demo (e.g. jsfiddle.net). http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michael_B I edited it, and sent a link to the codepen

Comment: The class name is misspelled in the media query.

Comment: @Michael_B Yup, fixed it, still doesn't work

Comment: With the typo fixed, the media query works fine here.

Comment: The link to the Codepen doesn't work (404 not found)

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS rule in a `style` tag inside your (HTML) `head`:

```
.nav-content {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
}
```

This overwrites the rules in all external style sheets...